# Can't boot anything

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows

I'm selling my laptop, so i decided to erase my Ubuntu partition, so i got the grub screen, at that point i could still access the boot menu trough initrd, but after following a tutorial in how to fix the boot and seeing no change i decided to activate UEFI again to see if it helped, it didn't, now i can't even access the boot menu, the initrd just bring me back to the grub screen, so now i now longer know to boot to Windows or a to LiveCD, or anything, so help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Can you rephrase the question to make it clear what you are wanting help with right now?

Comment: The question is unclear :( What do you **currently** want to do with it? Disk erase or something else?

Comment: You can erase your disk by booting from a live CD/DVD/USB media. You have to select the boot device inside your UEFI boot menu, not GRUB. But you have to take care that you are not only erasing the partitions, but the boot sector as well, otherwise you will still get to the GRUB rescue console. And be aware that deleting a partition is NOT nuking the data it contained. Advanced tools can still restore it. Formatting each partition (no quick format!) is better, but the safest option is to download a tool that overwrites all data several times on the disk. Don't know whether `dd` can do that too

Comment: Are you just going to leave a completely blank disk with no OS? That's easier than fixing boot problems. And the tools to recover a quickly deleted partition (not overwritten with anything) (or file) can be *very* easy to use too

Answer (score 0):

You can erase your disk by booting from a live CD/DVD/USB media. You have to select the boot device inside your UEFI boot menu, not GRUB.

But you have to take care that you are not only erasing the partitions, but the boot sector as well, otherwise you will still get to the GRUB rescue console.

And be aware that deleting a partition is NOT nuking the data it contained. Advanced tools can still restore it. Formatting each partition (no quick format!) is better, but the safest option is to download a tool that overwrites all data several times on the disk.
Don't know whether the built-in `dd` command can do that too or whether it will damage the hdd (it is also known as `d`isk `d`estroyer) . Never play with this command at your own without knowing what you're doing, it can be evil!